# Orientation of the barycentric subdivision

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Two orderings of the vertices of an $n$-simplex are said to be *equivalent* if they differ by an even permutation. An *orientation* of an $n$-simplex is a choice of one of the two equivalence classes of the vertex orderings. An *orientation* of a simplicial complex $X$ is a choice of orientation of each simplex $\sigma \in X$ and an *oriented* simplicial complex is a simplicial complex with a choice of orientation.

The \emph{first barycentric subdivision} of a simplicial complex $X$ is the simplicial complex $X'$ with simplices $\hat{\sigma_0} \ldots \hat{\sigma_n}$ where $\sigma_0 < \ldots < \sigma_n \in X$.

Suppose that $X$ is an oriented simplicial complex. One way to induce an orientation on the first barycentric subdivision $X'$ of $X$ is as follows.
Suppose that $\eta = \hat{\sigma_0} \ldots \hat{\sigma_n} \in X'$ is an $n$-simplex and $\sigma_n \in X$ is also an $n$-simplex. We may label the vertices of $\sigma_n$ as $v_0, \ldots, v_n$ in such a way that $\hat{\sigma_i}$ is the barycentre of the simplex $v_0 \ldots v_i \in X$. Then $\hat{\sigma_0} \ldots \hat{\sigma_n}$ is considered to represent the positive orientation of $\eta$ if $v_0 \ldots v_n$ represents the positive orientation of $\sigma_n \in X$. Since not all simplices of $X'$ are of the form $\hat{\sigma_0} \ldots \hat{\sigma_n}$ where $\sigma_n \in X$ is an $n$-simplex, we just choose arbitrary orientations for the remaining $n$-simplices.

Are there other ways to induce orientations of $X'$ from an orientation of $X$ (making use of the subdivision chain map $C_*(X)\rightarrow C_*(X')$ for example) which avoid the making of arbitrary choices of orientations of certain simplices of $X'$?